# Smoothness of a bundle over $\mathbb{P}^m$ with fiber $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^N_k \times \mathbb{P}^m_k$ and denote the projection map to $\mathbb{P}^m$ by 
\begin{equation}
\pi: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^m
\end{equation}
If for every $k$ valued point $p$ in $\mathbb{P}^m$, its fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$ in $Y$ is $\mathbb{P}^m$, how could we show that $Y$ is smooth?

E. g, if $\mathbb{P}^2$ has projective coordinates $x_0,~x_1,~x_2$ and $\mathbb{P}^5$ has coordinates $a_{00},a_{01},a_{02},a_{11},a_{12},a_{22}$, the universal plane conic $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^5$ is the scheme cut out by the equation,
\begin{equation}
a_{00}x_0^2+a_{01}x_0 x_1+\cdots+a_{22} x_{2}^2=0
\end{equation}

$\mathcal{C}$ is a $\mathbb{P}^4$-bundle over $\mathbb{P}^2$. How to prove $C$ is smooth using this property?